# Find repeated cell in 2D array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have 3x3 matrix as:

```
 1 -1 0  0
 1  2 2  1
 1  1 1 -1
-1  0 3  6
```

I am trying to find the diagonal elements of the cell that has value = -1, and multiplying the diagonal cell ([i-1][j-1],[i-1][j+1],[i+1][j-1],[i+1][j+1]) values with 2. So far I have achieved this but it seems that the cell [1][2] i.e. second row third column,is diagonal to 2 cells, which are [0][1] and [2][3]. So, my resulting array which should look like this:

```
 1 -1 0  0
 2  2 4  1
 1  2 1 -1
-1  0 6  6
```

instead looks like this:

```
 1 -1 0  0
 2  2 8  1
 1  2 1 -1
-1  0 6  6
```

i.e. there is a value 8 instead of 4 in cell [1][2]. So how can I check if the cell has already visited once and multiplied by 2 so that it cannot be multiplied again. Here is the code that i tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
            if (resultArray[i][j] == -1) {
                if (isAdjacent(i - 1, j - 1, x, y))
                    resultArray[i - 1][j - 1] *= 2;
                if (isAdjacent(i - 1, j + 1, x, y))
                    resultArray[i - 1][j + 1] *= 2;
                if (isAdjacent(i + 1, j - 1, x, y))
                    resultArray[i + 1][j - 1] *= 2;
                if (isAdjacent(i + 1, j + 1, x, y))
                    resultArray[i + 1][j + 1] *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
return resultArray;

static boolean isAdjacent(int i, int j, int x, int y) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (i >= 0 && i <= x && j >= 0 && j <= y) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;

}
```

Comment: I am not very proficient with java. I understood what you trying to say but I am unable to code the that. So accordingly mu next quest would be how do i store the cell positions in a 2D array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a two dimensional boolean array with true or false at the positions that are diagonal to the -1's and then update the matrix by multiplying all of the numbers at the true positions by two in your matrix. This way no values will be multiplied twice.

So you could initialize the boolean array:

```
boolean diagonalsArray[][] = new boolean[x][y];
```

and then instead of  multiplying the positions

```
resultArray[i + 1][j + 1] *= 2;
```

set those positions to true in your boolean array:

```
diagonalsArray[i + 1][j + 1] = true;
```

and between your for loop and return resultArray, do all the multiplying

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
               if(diagonalsArray[i][j]){
                    resultArray[i][j] *= 2;
                 }
            }
    }
```